# Pandas average of the difference between any two consecutive rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
name   date         quantity
'A'    2016-12-02   20
'A'    2016-12-04   5
'A'    2016-11-30   10
'B'    2016-11-30   10
...
```

What I want to do is calculate, for any pair of *consecutive* dates (consecutive as in chronological) for a name, the difference in the quantity, and the average these counts for a name.

Dates are indeed not necessarily presented in a chronological ordering.

Specifically, for name `A` I'd want to compute +10 (difference 2nd Dec - 30 Nov) and -15 (difference 4th Dec -2nd Nov) and then average those, to get a final result of -2.5 for this name.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `apply` [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html):

```
print (df.groupby('name')['quantity'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean()).reset_index())
  name  quantity
0  'A'      -2.5
1  'B'       NaN
```

EDIT: You can add [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `date`

```
print (df.sort_values('date')
         .groupby('name')['quantity']
         .apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean())
         .reset_index())
  name  quantity
0  'A'      -2.5
1  'B'       NaN
```

Comment: Great but sorry I did not specify the dates are necessarily ordered. Would I have to sort after the groupby and before the apply to stay safe?

Comment: Are you afraid about change ordering? I think there is no problem. Or do you need first sort dataframe by column `date` ?

Comment: Maybe the best is add sample data with desired output.

Comment: Changed the example to get rid of the edge case of ordered dates.