# Pandas average of the ratio of column differences between any two consecutive rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a follow-up on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038400/pandas-average-of-the-difference-between-any-two-consecutive-rows-in-dataframe/41038464?noredirect=1#comment69285354_41038464). I report an example dataframe for convenience:

```
name   date         quantity
'A'    2016-12-02   20
'A'    2016-12-03   5
'A'    2016-11-30   10
'B'    2016-11-30   10
...
```

What I need to do is calculating the average of the ratios defined as

> difference of quantity / difference in dates (in number of days)

for each name. Differences have to be computed for chronologically ordered dates and the dataframe does not necessarily present them ordered.

The previous question allows me to compute the average of the numerators, how would I go about doing the average of the full ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom function `f` with [`dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) for convert `Timedelta` to `days`and divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
def f(x):
    d = x.date.diff().dt.days
    q = x.quantity.diff()
    return (q.div(d)).mean()

df1 = df.sort_values('date').groupby('name').apply(f).reset_index(name='ratio')
print (df1)
  name  ratio
0  'A'   -5.0
1  'B'    NaN
```